# VBS 2D Dynamic Array does not work in VB6

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I'm converting some **VBS** code to **VB6**. Most of the exercise is a copy and paste affair, except for this function,

```
Public Function TestMe()

    Dim RowCount: RowCount = -1
    Dim FieldCount: FieldCount = -1
    ReDim ANames(RowCount, FieldCount)
    MsgBox UBound(ANames)

End Function
```

The code compiles fine in **VBS**. However I get a different result when I use this function in VB6.

In **VBS** this shows message -1

In **VB6** this shows message Subscript out of range

Why is this and how can I convert this to **VB6**?

Comment: Please show more code, and the line where you get the error.

Comment: added the function and rephrased some details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBScript, Redimming an array so that its UBound is -1 is a way to mark the array an empty array. In VB6, negative bounds are possible, but *upper bounds must be >= lower bounds*. Consider the following:

```
Public Function TestMe()

    Dim RowCount: RowCount = -1
    Dim FieldCount: FieldCount = -1
    ReDim ANames(-2 To RowCount, -2 To FieldCount)
    ANames(-1, -1) = "Hi"
    MsgBox ANames(-1, -1)

End Function
```

In VB6, this runs without a hitch, popping up "Hi" as expected.

As far as a workaround, if `ANames` is an array variable, you can simply use

```
Erase ANames
```

Rather than your `ReDim`. Similarly if `ANames` is a variant variable (but not an array variable), just assign `Empty` to it.

Comment: Accepted answer, thanks John, this helped to resolve my issue!